# Looking for a Public WPS Service

Tags: wps

Can anyone point me to a public WPS (Web Processing Service)?  I need to do some testing on it and results in Google and Bing show nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a good list here at least to start testing with.

CIESIN

http://beta.sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/wps/WebProcessingService?Request=GetCapabilities&Service=WPS

CIESIN

http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/mapserver/map/HOTSPOTSv1?Request=GetCapabilities&Version=1.1.1&Service=WMS

GEMS/WATER

http://www.gemstat.org/WS/stationByCountry.aspx?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

GRID/GENEVA GEO

http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/webservices/">directory -

GRID/GENEVA GEO

http://gridca.grid.unep.ch/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/www/geodataportal/htdocs/mod_map/geo_wms.map&service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=getcapabilities

GRID-Arendal

http://maps.continentalshelf.org/wfsconnector/com.esri.wfs.Esrimap/osdsF?request=getcapabilities

GRID-Arendal

http://maps.continentalshelf.org/wmsconnector/com.esri.wms.Esrimap/shelfdatashop?request=getcapabilities&service=WMS&version=1.1.1

GRID-Nairobi

http://gridnairobi.unep.org/aimscsw/csw2.0?request=GetCapabilities&version=2.0.0&service=CSW

GRID-Sioux Falls

http://na.unep.net/cgi-bin/global_postgis?request=getcapabilities&Service=wms&version=1.1.1">here

ICIMOD

http://216.108.232.20:8080/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW&acceptVersions=2.0.1&acceptFormats=application%2Fxml

ICIMOD

http://216.108.232.20:8080/geoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

NDIDC

http://nsidc.org/cgi-bin/atlas_north?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

NDIDC

http://nsidc.org/cgi-bin/atlas_south?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

UNEP PREVIEW

http://preview.grid.unep.ch:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities

UNEP PREVIEW

http://preview.grid.unep.ch:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

UNEP/DEWA

http://dewa03.unep.org/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities
UNEP/DEWA

http://dewa03.unep.org/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities

WCMC

http://maps.unep-wcmc.org/arcgis/services/WDPAv2_0/wdpa_all_WGS84/MapServer//WFSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS

WCMC

http://maps.unep-wcmc.org/arcgis/services/WDPAv2_0/wdpa_all_WGS84/MapServer//WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

Comment: Downvoted the answer since the list is primarily of WMS/WFS services, not WPS, as the question says.

Comment: Hey OP, would it be possible to maybe update this list a bit? I've suggested an edit to remove those that I've found that are just 404, but some other seem to have either changed route (as the site still exists) or disappeared as well.